# Blazor Authentication to handle Login and Logout Using CustomStateProvider

Tags: authentication, cookies, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor working on Visual Studio 2022 with .Net 6. I am facing an Issue I want to store User Claims in my Server Side, and If user is Authenticated then my dashboard page must be loaded otherwise loginComponent will be rendered. It works fine on first load once I enter the username password my stateProvide SetAuthenticationStateAsync mehtod is called and redirect to Dashboard is working, now If I click on reload button of my browser GetAuthenticationStateAsync gives me Null value due to which it redirects me again to login page. I just want to get the working that if user is logged in his data must be available on all pages untile unless  user click the logout button. Here is my code of each page

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SagErpBlazor.Data
{
 public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
 {
    private AuthenticationState _authenticationState;
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public async Task SetAuthenticationStateAsync(AuthenticationState authenticationState)
    {
        _authenticationState = authenticationState;
      
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(authenticationState));

       
     
    }
   


    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        // Return the authentication state stored in memory
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
      
    }


 }
```

This is my Login Component Code

@code {

```
private async Task SignInClick()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
    {
        ModalBodyText = "Please Enter Your Correct Username, Password to Proceed further..";
        IsModalVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        var EncryptedPassword = EncryptionHelper.DefaultEncrypt(Password, EncryptionHelper.DefaultKey);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select * from gluser left outer join GLUserBranchDetail b on GLUser.Userid=b.Userid where GLUser.UserPassword='" + EncryptedPassword + "' and GLUser.UserName= '" + Username + "'", DataBaseService.GetSqlConnection());
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"]) + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["LastName"])));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["UserName"])));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor, Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Userid"])));
            claims.Add(new Claim("CompanyID", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["CompanyID"])));
            claims.Add(new Claim("Fiscalid", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Fiscalid"])));

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            { };

            var authState = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

            // Set the user's authentication state using the custom AuthenticationStateProvider.
            var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider;
           await customAuthStateProvider.SetAuthenticationStateAsync(authState);

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve // Handle circular references
                };

            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", "authState", JsonSerializer.Serialize(authState, options));
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Counter");
        }
        else
        {

            ModalBodyText = "Please Enter Your Correct Username, Password to Proceed further..";
            IsModalVisible = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
    
}
```

This is my Main layout where I am checking user identity

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@code {
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var customAuthStateProvider = 
      (CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider;
    var authState = await customAuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    if (authState is null)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/LoginComponent");
    }
    else
    {

        var user = authState.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/LoginComponent");
        }
        else
        {
            var isClassAdded = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", 
             "isClassAdded");
            if (isClassAdded!="true")
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("addClassToBody", "nav-function-top");
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", "isClassAdded", 
         "true");
            }
        }
    }


    }
   }
```